# Unified infrastructure monitoring tool

Tags: tooltip, monitoring, mainframe, infrastructure

I am looking for a tool which is similar to CA UIM, but in open source. I would like the tools to monitor mainly our HP enclosures, blades, interconnect bays along with the virtualised server installed on each HP enclosure.

Comment: I found a few here https://www.channele2e.com/2016/01/21/top-50-cloud-monitoring-and-management-tools-which-are-best/ but I am not sure which is the best and freely available.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for my score going (-1). I also don't require the badge for commenting.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect it is because tool-requests are off-topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: StackOverflow is about programming questions, not find-a-tool questions. There is a software recommendations site, but be sure to read the help centre on how to ask there, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.  Why the Mainframe tag, from your question there is no Mainframe involved? What's the tooltip tag for? The -1 on the question doesn't affect your overall score, because it cannot go below one anyway. I'm not sure how realistic it is to expect a full monitoring tool for free, but maybe there is something for what you want.

Comment: PS - Agree with Bill that this shouldn't be posted as a mainframe question...

Answer (score -1):

Depends how deep you need to go with monitoring.

If your needs are basic, Nagios, Chef and Graylog combined can generally get you pretty close.